# Why is pure sample covariance a bad metric to understand the degree of correlation between two variables?

Tags: correlation, covariance

Covariance helps you understand how variables are linearly related.

Would it be possible to have two pairs of variables in a deterministic relationship (i.e. linearly correlated variables) that have *different* values for the covariance?

My guess would be that if you had one pair with low sample variances and the other pair with high sample variances, you could have the same relationship but a different covariance. Am I on the right path?

Comment: Because it is not invariant under scaling.

Comment: So you mean the covariance accounts for the differences in variance, but a measure like the correlation doesn't?

Comment: I mean that if heights are measured in inches, the covariance is very different from the covariance if heights are measured in feet. Correlation coefficient is by contrast invariant under scaling.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help!